# C# Assign Value from Dynamic Data Reader to variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have a `count query` on my program which result is assigned to a Dynamic Data Reader variable. I need to assign the result of that count to an `int` variable. While debbuging I can see that the count result is there as can be seen below, the result is `3142`:

[image]

The problem here is that I not being able to assign that value from the `Dynamic` to an `int` variable. Any ideas?

I'm trying the following way:

```
dynamic dreader = new DynamicDataReader(rawReader);
                var count = (int)dreader["Value"];
```

the `rawReader` is the result of the Query executed

Comment: Post your code as well.

Comment: I edited the post. There's not much code to add. The data is there, I don't know how to assign that result to an int variable

Answer (score 0):

Try Integer.Parse() instead - or Integer.TryParse() if you want to find out whether the value can be transformed to int at all.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot find the value, that solution I put on my post is not working. I don't know how to assign that value displayed on the image to the variable

Comment: So your problem isn't the convertion but accessing the value? Try this article perhaps:  https://www.codeproject.com/articles/201878/http%3a%2f%2fmrbigglesworth79.blogspot.com%2f2011%2f05%2fdata-access-using-dynamics-part-i.html

Comment: are you sure that link is correct is redirecting to nowhere

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/201878/http%3a%2f%2fmrbigglesworth79.blogspot.com%2f2011%2f05%2fdata-access-using-dynamics-part-i.html

Comment: It's Data Access with dynamics Part I https://duckduckgo.com/?q=DynamicDataReader+C%23&t=iphone&ia=qa

Comment: My problem is that I don't have a column name on my dynamic to get the data, I put it as COUNT but if I do `dreader.Count` it throws exception that Count is not defined on the object

Comment: what about .COUNT? Case sensitive? !

Comment: no, I put on the same way, I was wrong on aboves comment, I put Count in both cases but I'ts not recognizing it as a property of the dynamic

Comment: I'm sorry. I must admit, I have no clue.

Comment: thanks anyway for taking all this time to help me :)

Comment: We all struggle. Keep on searching, you'll find a solution, sooner or later.